# Not understanding datetime delta in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

`from datetime import datetime as dt`

I have 2 datetime fields

`dt.now()` returns **2019-01-08 11:46:26.035303**
This is PST

x is my dataset

`x['CreatedDate']` returns **2019-01-08T20:35:47.000+0000**

`dt.strptime(x['CreatedDate'.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)) - datetime.timedelta(hours=8)` returns **2019-01-08 08:43:33**

I subtract the two, 
`tdelta = dt.now() - (dt.strptime(x['CreatedDate'.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)) - datetime.timedelta(hours=8))`
which is **2019-01-08 11:46:26.035303** - **2019-01-08 08:43:33**

The difference should be ~3 hours but the result I'm getting is `-1 day, 11:02:53.039790`
-13H 12M 53S

I'm confused as to what is being returned.

Comment: I don't see how this code works, as your format string `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` contains a `T` separating the day and hour fields, but your date string `2019-01-08 08:43:33` does not have the `T`.  Also your date string has microseconds as the last field, but your date format does not have that field.

Comment: If you post the code that shows how you are assigning your datetime variables and then how you are subtracting them, this will likely be pretty easy to solve. For example, `x = datetime.now()`, `y = datetime.strptime('2019-01-08 08:43:33','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, `diff = x - y`

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**

I am having a tough time making the `datetime` objects that you made. So, my answer will not be a direct solution to your exact problem.

I dont have `x` defined in my code. If you supply it, I can adjust my answer to be more specific.

**Answer**

But if you use this code:

```
import datetime as dt

first_time = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 8, 8, 43, 33) #This is a good way to make a datetime object
```

To make your datetime object then this code below will make the correct calculations and print it effectively for you:

```
second_time = dt.datetime.now() 
my_delta = first_time - second_time
print("Minutes: " + str(my_delta.total_seconds()/60))
print("Hours: " + str(my_delta.total_seconds()/3600))
print("Days: " + str(my_delta.total_seconds()/3600/24))
```

**Note**

`dt.datetime` takes (year, month, day, hour, minute, second) here but `dt.datetime.now()` is making one with microseconds as well (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microseconds). The function can handle being given different time specificities without error.

**Note 2**

If you do `print(my_delta)` and get something like: `-1 day, 16:56:54.481901` this will equate to your difference if your difference is `Hours: -7.051532805277778` This is because `24-16.95 = -7.05`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the subtraction of datetime.timedelta(hours=8) I removed that from changed the dt.now to dt.utcnow() and it works fine.